# How to run dev server in debug mode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My app was written on top of [vuejs-templates/pwa boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa).

I've added a proxy to dev server config (`build/webpack.dev.conf.js`):

```
devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target:       'https://staging-api.company.net',
                pathRewrite:  {"^/api": ""},
                secure:       true,
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
        },
    },
```

It obviously doesn't work on first try, but I want to debug it to know how the proxy is redirecting the requests. I'd like to see in command line output some logs, something like:

```
Redirecting from /api/user/bla to https://staging-api.company.net/user/bla
```

But currently when I run `yarn dev`, when compilation is done all I see is:

> Listening at http://localhost:8000

and after that the cli is silent.

I've tried to add an option to `webpack-dev-middleware` in `build/dev-server.js`:

```
const devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    // quiet: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
});
```

but it doesn't help, I'm not getting any new output in cli when I trigger requests from my app.

Comment: Tried `DEBUG=*` environment variable?

Comment: where? how? I added `process.env.DEBUG = true` to `dev-server.js` but it's not changing anything.

Comment: In linux, I do `export DEBUG=*` in the terminal. Or, `DEBUG=* node path/to/file.js` or `DEBUG=* <command>`

Comment: mhm, but I've searched for usage of this variable in webpack source files and there was no reference to `DEBUG` variable

Comment: Doesn't webpack have option to add environment variables?

Comment: How do you run the webpack command & what OS do you use?